# Jquery: Select one class out of multiple classes with same name?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to choose one class from the parent element that I've clicked in a list format. All the while preventing the other classes with the same class name from showing.

So, for example:

```
$('ul').click(function() {
    $('li').next(".info").css({ "display" : "block" });
});
```

While I have `.info` set to `display:none;`

And my html code is:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Guy</span></li>
    <li class="info">
        <p>This should pop up when I click on the "Guy" span.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Although, I can't seem to figure out why it won't work/fire.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the event to the *span* elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul span').click(function() {
        // $('.info').hide()
        $(this).parent().next().show();
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2mvdt/

Comment: I'm not sure what's still wrong, but even though that worked in fiddle, it didn't work for me.

Comment: @jsksma2 The structure of your markup should be the same as in the fiddle.

Comment: I'm retarded. There was other classes that were listed before the `.info` class. I simply needed to switch them around. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

You're targeting the wrong element, basically. Simply use:

```
$('ul li').click(
    function(){
        $(this).next('li.info').show();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uBsX3/).

In your original code `$(this)` is the `ul` that was clicked (the `click` event bubbles from the clicked `li` or `span` up to the `ul`), and then looks for the next sibling of the `ul` that *also* has the class name of `info`.

My amendment works by having the target of the `click` event be the `li`, which *has* got a sibling element with the class of `info`.

Incidentally, on those occasions where jQuery doesn't work, it's helpful to do `console.log($(this))` just to check your selector's matching what you think it should be matching.

Comment: When I used `console.log($(this));` it returned `[span]`.

Comment: [Not with the HTML and code you posted in your question it doesn't](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uBsX3/1/) (at least, not in Chromium 18).